# Scale Img by Pixel Size

Tags: html, css

I have a box with text, an image, and more text, each of which load dynamically.

The problem is that the images are of varying size and either overflow the space available to them, or don't fill it up.

For example, I have this working case ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EL_C905/ezg01vo4/2/)):

```css
.tBox {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: #222831;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  align-content: center;
  color: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.imgText {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-Top: 2em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.tBoxNoBorder {
  height: 300px;
}

.graphic {
  justify-Content: center;
  align-Content: center;
  text-Align: center;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 30vw;
}

.imgGraphic {
  width: 50%;
  margin-Top: 3%;
}

.imgConclusion {
  float: right;
  margin-Right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.legend {
  padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
  background: #d65a31;
  border-radius: 25px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 3vmax 2vmin;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.imgDiv {
  justify-Content: center;
  align-Content: center;
  text-Align: center;
  left: 50%;
}

.img {
  width: 30%;
  margin-Top: 3%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset class="tBox">
    <legend class="legend">The best QBDs have:</legend>
    <div class="imgText">Almost No Thinking: You should not need to be subjective. Claim each item as 0/100 (it’s either completed or it isn’t)

      Proportionate Items: To give the best output, the individual elements should be of similar size

      Simple &amp; Manageable: It should be easy to use and not require significantly more work

      Complement The Schedule: The QBD should not be used for detailed planning, rolling wave or a schedule. It should be a checklist of criteria for achieving a task </div>
    <div class="imgDiv"><img class="imgGraphic" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1v4K09NaRaMUDvlXKazMtdEF6cBPKc2eI" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imgConclusion">Clear guidelines!</div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

But then I also have this guy ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EL_C905/9dek7cfw/)):

```css
.tBox {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: #222831;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  align-content: center;
  color: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.imgText {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-Top: 2em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.tBoxNoBorder {
  height: 300px;
}

.graphic {
  justify-Content: center;
  align-Content: center;
  text-Align: center;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 30vw;
}

.imgGraphic {
  width: 50%;
  margin-Top: 3%;
}

.imgConclusion {
  float: right;
  margin-Right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.legend {
  padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
  background: #d65a31;
  border-radius: 25px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 3vmax 2vmin;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.imgDiv {
  justify-Content: center;
  align-Content: center;
  text-Align: center;
  left: 50%;
}

.img {
  width: 30%;
  margin-Top: 3%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="compGraphic">
  <fieldset class="tBox">
    <legend class="legend">So...</legend>
    <div class="imgText">For Karen, that means her performance looks like this...</div>
    <div class="imgDiv"><img class="imgGraphic" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=13NKquqxlGJc9snU54sytPWbenwr7TRUU" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imgConclusion">...Yikes!</div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Notice how in the second example, the image doesn't fill to the bottom. Note, `tBox` will resize based on screen size, but should always be bigger than its contents.

I've tried setting max heights/widths using vw/vh, and position: absolute, but to no avail - the images never seem to stay centered or never quite fit.

The best I've managed to do consider is adjusting `width` on `.imgGraphic`, but I'm not sure how to do that dynamically based on the img pixel size. It also seems inelegant. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, First change the following CSS properties:

```
justify-Content to justify-content
text-Align to text-align
margin-Top to margin-top
...
```

These properties are usually in lower case letters.

### Suggested CSS

```
.tBox {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: #222831;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    align-content: center;
    color: #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }

  .imgText {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }

  .tBoxNoBorder {
    height: 300px;
  }

  .imgGraphic{
    max-height: 250px;
    width: auto;
  }

  .imgConclusion {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }

  .legend {
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    background-color: #d65a31;
    border-radius: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    font-size: 3vmax 2vmin;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }

  .imgDiv {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3% auto;
  }
```

The reason I set the max-height to 250px because you specified that the `.tBox` size isn't going to change.

The `.imgDiv` is the image container so it was used to center the image.